How to give terminal sound effects for dopamine?
We’ve all seen the movies where main guy boots up a terminal and the text flies across the screen character by character while a short sequence of computer blips proceeds.
The idea is quite simple, actually… Note: that I am not a programmer, but I have spent countless hours turned into days in trying to do something so simple and troubleshooting this mess. I modified bashrc files so many times that I’ve had to reinstall Linux because I didn’t know how to make a proper backup. I’ve consulted with people on Reddit, they also seem clueless. I’ve even had ChatGPT write me several scripts which never seem to work properly or exactly the way I want. Again, the Idea is simple: To have a script (or scripts) that can handle the following tasks:

It can play a sound (not terminal beep “\a”) for every keypress and when within the terminal window specifically.

Have every command output accompanied by a sound.

Have the ability to toggle of these features within the command line itself.

Having a stylized terminal output in which each character is “expressed” one by one (such as a typewriter effect) accompanied by a sound, whilst still having full command line functionality.


I have encountered a few errors on my own, for one, it seems that the sound and the “terminal output are never synchronized. I have sort of fixed this by adding “&” to keep it as a sound process. These are obviously optimization problems it seems to me.
Overall I think this should make for a pretty fun and hopefully easy to fix project for most of ya “Linux users” anyway lol. I would appreciate any help/advice I can get. Thank you.

Please edit your question and add the following details: a) which Ubuntu release you are using, b) which Terminal you intend to use - there are plenty for Linux -  the standard for Ubuntu for the interactive terminal is BASH and c) which code you tried and doesn't work.

And please try to clarify the requirements. After reading several times, I still don't understand what you want. I have never seen a movie with this level of weird tech. A sound for every character!? It is absolutely possible, of course, but your description is a bit vague. Same sound for every character? Different? What does "stylized terminal output in which each character is “expressed” one by one (such as a typewriter effect) accompanied by a sound, whilst still having full command line functionality" mean? You want a delay after every single character of output? And full functionality?
